# How to update a h:inputHidden with p:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I writed an ajax request for any data. But the data don't work with h:inputHidden.
I think it's a bug of Primefaces.
But I don't know how to get the data now.

code:

```
<h:inputHidden id="buttonData" value="#{buttonDataBean.buttonData}" />
...
<p:commandButton id="getData" action="#{buttonAction.getButtonData}" update="buttonData" />
```

When I click the commandButton, the value of  don't work.
But if I use the h:outputText, it worked.

My requirement:
Before click the commandButton, I have create any html buttons dynamically. I want to click the commandButton and update the name and position of html buttons. So that I must get any data and update the html buttons with Javascript.
how could I do about it?

If I want to use the JavaScript to get the ajax data, how to do it. I see the document and find two method: jsf.ajax.request() and Primefaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(). But I don't know how to use the two method. for example: Primefaces.ajax.AjaxRequest("test.xhtml",,). The "test.xhtml" how to request the method testMethod of TestAction?

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that it "don't work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use firebug to inspect html code. you can see new value

```
<h:form id="form">
  <h:inputHidden  id="buttonData" value="#{buttonDataBean.buttonData}" />
  <p:commandButton id="getData" value="button"
                   action="#{buttonDataBean.buttonAction}" update="buttonData" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem does not get solved with primefaces ajax, you can use the native ajax provided by jsf  have a look at it.It works, i have done many such things with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hidden input you could take advantage of JSF and use a `f:param` or `f:attribute`.

Read this really fine article, under the brand of BalusC: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html .